# When are Keeper actions available?

Tags: fluxx

In Star Fluxx, some Keepers give you abilities that don't take up an action. Are Keeper abilities in Star Fluxx available immediately after the Keeper is put on the table, on the next turn, or just the next time you have an action available?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is the answer from Loney Labs (Alison Looney)

> We would rule that you can use the power of a Keeper as soon as you
>   play it.  There's no way it would depend upon keeper or hand limits,
>   or play rules.  Your turn is not over until you have taken all
>   optional extra actions, including those based on special Keeper powers
>   and extra actions on Rules.  So, as soon as you play that Keeper (or
>   that Rule) you can do what it says you can do, because your turn is
>   not over until you have taken (or decided not to take) that optional
>   extra action.
>
> It may happen that a Keeper power has no effect at a given time. 
>   Example: in Star Fluxx, you could steal a crew member with the Captain
>   as soon as you play the Captain - but if no other players have crew
>   members on the table to steal, then that's not going to be an option. 
>   Another example: In Zombie Fluxx you could kill a Zombie with your
>   Shotgun as soon as you play the Shotgun, but if there are no Zombies
>   to kill, obviously nothing's going to happen.

Answer (score 1):

All keeper actions can be triggered from the moment they enter play (unless otherwise stated).

However, if that keeper is your final play, your turn immediately ends and you will not be able to trigger any ability that requires it to be your turn.

Watch your play order and you can pop anything the turn it comes out.

Comment: Are you sure about the "however"? For example, if only the Rich Bonus rule is in place, and you play a keeper, which causes you to now have more keepers than anyone else, you would still get to play another card due to the bonus, right?

Comment: _However, if that keeper is your final play .. you will not be able to trigger any ability that requires it to be your turn_ - So, you want to say that you need first to play a card, then draw a card in order for the effects to be usable in that turn ? If you always first draw a card, then play, your last card played will never take effect in that turn?

Comment: I think I got it. In manual http://goo.gl/sdDlN they say in **On your turn** section that you must first *draw* then *play* then do 2 more actions (obey limits). The rules also say **Optional actions allowed by Keepers may be performed at any point during this sequence**. Since *play* rule is the second action out of 4 you can always trigger the keeper action and it should hold even if there are no _hand/keeper limit_ rules in play since you still play those moves even tho they are not applicable.

Comment: Anyway, I never noticed that there is play order, so you must not play before drawing which does make sense since you could get creeper that can prevent you from winning.

Comment: @GendoIkari, yes, you would get another action if your last play changed the rules so that you get more actions. If Play 1 is in effect, and you add Play All, then you get all of those additional actions.

Comment: To Clarify my "However", I use the term "Final" to mean the absolute last play allowed by the current cards and rules. If playing that keeper would mean you have ZERO remaining actions, your turn ends.

Comment: @JaredTritsch, your *final* is too vague. For instance, is it final if I play a card then have no limiting rules in play? And what do you mean by watch your play order and you can pop out anything ? There is nothing to watch since you have no choice in order. Do you mean that when I proclaimed my turn as finished then I can't do actions (since its not my turn any more).

Comment: Found what "final" means - Andrew Looney said on forum its when you say it, move fuzzy creature, or move token