# can keepers kill creepers in same turn over and over again?

Tags: fluxx

In Monty Python Fluxx, there are keepers that kill creepers.

Can they be played and also kill in the same turn, or is it 1 turn to play them and 2nd turn to kill?

Also, can they be used over and over again?

Comment: possible duplicate of [When are Keeper actions available?](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/13342/when-are-keeper-actions-available)

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know the wording of the cards in this version of Fluxx. If the creeper says "if you have the XXX keeper, discard this" then it's constant (as with scurvy/oranges in Pirate Fluxx). If the keeper says "remove XXX creeper", then it's when you play the keeper, as described in [this question](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/13342/when-are-keeper-actions-available).

Comment: I've found the text for Excalibur: "If you have this on the table, you may move one of your Creepers to another player during your turn." You can use this once per turn, since the card cares about already being on the table.

Answer (score 2):

*Disclaimer: I don't have this edition of Fluxx, so I may not have found all of the relevant keepers.*

**Yes.** The keepers with creeper removal *from this edition* specifically care about being on the table. It only takes one of your plays to actually play a card, **not to use an effect they provide**. These "free" actions can be taken at any time (in between card plays) unless specified otherwise.

The relevant keepers are as follows:

> 1. **Excalibur**: If you have this on the table, you may move one of your Creepers to another player during your turn.
> 2. **Holy Hand Grenade of Antioch**: If you have this on the table and it's your turn, you can discard it along with any Creeper of your choice.
> 3. **Finger of God**: If you have this on the table you may smite (i.e. discard) any Creeper. After smiting, you must put this card back into your hand.
> 4. **The Animator**: Counts as the Finger of God if the real Finger of God is not on the table.

1. Excalibur specifies "**one** of **your** Creepers **during your turn**", so you can do this once per turn.
2. You can use this "during **your turn**", but only once because it's discarded, unless you have a way to recover it from the discard and play it again.
3. You can use this at any time between plays. If it's your turn and you have multiple plays, you can repeatedly play and use this card.
4. If this counts as the Finger of God, it copies all the properties of that card, so it **can** be used to smite.

Comment: So for example if I have the play all rule in play I could get rid of all my creepers with  the finger of god?

Comment: Well I think your turn ends immediately after your last play (I'd need to check that), but as long as you had a spare card in hand, yes.

Answer (score 0):

To add to this, in Space Fluxx, there are two Keepers that can kill any kind of creeper, and two Keepers that can remove a single type of Creeper.

However, all of them start the kill description with "Once per turn".  So, these are specifically kept at this level.